# Mysql local to live import export

Tags: mysql, opencart

I have a database in MySQL in which there are 700 products in a table. I want to update this table's data on live URL.
        The live database is already created, what to do now?

Comment: is that an opencart database (database with 700 products)?

Comment: @SankarV yes, it is